# boolean logic on multiple rows of an sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

supposing I have the following data:

```
id  name  source
-----------------
1   'n'   'a'
1   'n'   'b'
1   'n'   'c'
1   'n'   'd'    
2   'n'   'a'
2   'n'   'c'
```

How can I select all ids that contain (source==a || source==f) && (source==c || source==g) ?

This is for MySQL...

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is here to help, otherwise you want rent-a-coder.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select unique id from table as t1
where (t1.source = 'a' or t1.source='f')
  and exists 
   (select * from table as t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and (t2.source = 'c' or t2.source='g')
    )
```

Comment: I think the my solution is more elegant, as it uses only join, no `exists` :P But thanks for the comment.

Comment: :-)) .... :) but anyway, I'm serious - isn't your solution quadratic? I mean - for a large number of rows, I'd be curious how much slower (if at all) this solution would be compared to the join.

Answer (score 0):

(**edit**: it's fixed now)

```
select id
from
    (select id
    from table
    where source = 'a' or source = 'f'
    group by id) as t1
join
    (select id
    from table
    where source = 'c' or source = 'g'
    group by id) as t2
using (id)
```

Comment: OK, sorry, the id is not id, but can be repeated! THat confused me.